# Can't repair grub file

Tags: boot, grub2

I have on old HP PC, Pavilion.
Have two drives on it, an older WD 500 MB storage drive, and a brand new WD 3 Terabyte sata drive.
Installed Ubuntu 20.04 on the new drive, but I can't get it to boot.

Continually getting a black screen with the message "Grub Rescue" and a blinker.
I have tried using the BOOT Repair tool downloaded on my "Live" version of Ubuntu (US stick), no joy there.

Using Gparted I can see the "/dev/sda1" listed as Grub2 core img,
/dev/sda2 as fat32/mnt/boot and /dev/sda3  as ext4/mnt/boot. sda3 is the largest partition 2.7 Tbs

I have been battling this for 3 days (and nights),now.
Could someone help me? 
Have been using Linux for about 4 years now, but I classify myself as a rank beginner, so keep it fairly simple please.
My log url is https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/85HVQMvhRw/

Comment: One clarification, Can you get into tty. Or grub menu ?  where you can edit the grub file. For grub menu press and hold right shift button. and for tty, you can use function keys Ctrl+Alt with function keys F3 to F6 and have four TTY sessions open

Comment: Can't boot at all

Answer (score 0):

Do not run auto-fix with multiple drives & multiple installs.

Usually best to use advanced mode and install grub into sda for install on sda drive and install grub for install on sdb to sdb's MBR.

It looks like grub in MBR of sda is looking for partition that does not exist. Or it is an old copy of grub and new install did not update it like it should have.

Install grub to sda's MBR.

https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

A partitioned install usually removes the LVM drivers. So sudo update-grub will not find your LVM install. You need to install lvm2 and if encrypted cryptsetup. Then manually mount LVM volumes & run the update of grub.

Comment: Tried advance mode.

Comment: no option to install grub to sda's MBR

Comment: Is there any advantage to be had by removing the physical second drive from the computer, at least temporarily?

Comment: It can work for first drive, but second drive gets changed to first and has hd0 entries that should be hd1. Did you boot Ubuntu live installer in BIOS mode? In advanced mode, you should be able to select install in sda & install grub to sda's MBR. And same with sdb, but may have to manually mount LVM first.